# Getting Spring RestTemplate to use an in-memory pem cert (not on disk)

Tags: spring, bouncycastle, resttemplate, pem, sslcontext

My Java/Spring program connects to Vault using a RestTemplate. My company's Operations team has a plan to provide a pem CA certificate to the application using an environment variable ($VAULT_CACERT).

The Java program is not allowed to change any files on disk (so adding the pem CA certificate to a disk-based truststore is not an option).

Is it possible to configure the Spring RestTemplate so that it uses an in-memory CA certificate (not from a disk-based jks file)?

I see that there is a Java API (java.security.KeyStore) and also a bouncycastle API (org.bouncycastle.tls.test.KeyStores) and am wondering if either of these could be used.

Answer (score 0):

https://jkutner.github.io/2016/05/12/java-truststore-keystore-from-env-vars.html shows how to construct an in-memory KeyStore object and then create an SSLContext from one.